# Syntax Error in dialog resource

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources, dialog

I have a Win32 GUI application and in my resource.rc file I'm trying to create a dialog, but I get a syntax error in my code.

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOG 0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU // error here
CAPTION "About"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
   DEFPUSHBUTTON "&OK", IDOK, 174, 27, 50, 14
   GROUPBOX "Blahblah...", IDC_STATIC, 7, 7, 225, 52
   CTEXT "Name: Blahblah\r\nVersion: blahblahblah\r\nAuthor: blahblahblah\r\nDescription: blahblahblah", IDC_STATIC, 15, 18, 144, 33
END
```

(Of course, it doesn't really say blahblahblah.)
I Google'd around and found some similar questions, but they were all to do with the groupbox line and IDC_STATIC not being declared.  IDC_STATIC isn't declared in mine either and if I hover over it, the 'tooltip' it gives is all the lines of my menu resource.  But I don't think this has anything to do with it, because its a different line that's causing the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

(In case its needed, I'm using CodeBlocks with MinGW on Windows 7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please forgive me if this is an irrelevant pointing out.
I think `STYLE`'s argument values like window style(`WS_`...) and dialog box
style(`DS_`...) are defined in a system header file.
So, probably `<windows.h>` or similar header file has to be `#include`ed
before the use of those values.
Hope this helps.

Comment: under mingw, #include <afxres.h> helps. This is more suitable include file for resource definition rather than windows.h or winuser.h

Comment: afxres is what fixed the problem for me. Wow!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this scenario, @Ise Wisteria's answer is great.  However, after that fix, I got the same error again, which turned out to be a little misleading.

My problem was in resource definition - turns out I was missing `IDC_STATIC` which threw the same syntax error for a different reason.

(Also using C::B MinGW Win7)